# Understanding Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, mathematical-programming

I am sorry if these are such stupid noob questions. I am just getting into CS.

I read a passage in a book that says:

> Time complexity is written T(n). It gives the number of operations the algorithm performs when processing an input of size n.
> We also refer to an algorithm’s T(n) as its running cost. If our code follows T(n) = n<sup>2</sup>, we can predict how much longer it takes to sort a deck once we double its size:

[image]

Questions:

1. Firstly, why does our code follow **T(n) = n<sup>2</sup>** ? I don't get why we make that assumption
2. I do not understand what this means, n<sup>2</sup> means squared, correct? so if `n` is `8` then it's: `T(8) = 64`, right?
3. Next we have the `T(2n)/T(n) = 4`, lets say `n` is `2` then its `T(4)/T(2) = 2`, right?

Again I am a noob so please be gently and I would really appreciate detailed answers. Thank you

Comment: You are happy with `T(8) = 64`. So you should be happy with `T(4) = 16` and `T(2) = 4`. Then `T(4)/T(2) = 16/4 = 4`, not `2`.

Answer (score 5):

1. This is just an example. Easiest to think of an algorithm that has two nested loops over an array of size $n$ (e.g. Bubble Sort).
2. You are correct. Again, if you think of an algorithm that has two nested loops and within the inner loop just one (or constantly many) operation $op$, then $op$ gets executed $n^2$ times. If you array has size 8, $op$ gets executed 64 times.
3. No, the ratio is constantly 4. $\frac{T(2n)}{T(n)} = \frac{(2n)^2}{n^2} = 4$. The intuition here is that quadratic runtime means: By $k$-folding the input size, the runtime gets $k^2$-folded.

Answer (score 0):

It means we try to express the time needed to solve a problem as a function of the problem size, so that we know how to deal with larger problem sizes & scalability issues

- For example if we find it is linear in the problem size (T(n)=an+b) that's probably cool, if n=1000 or even n=10⁹ we can manage (our program will end its run in a acceptable time)
- While if we calculate it to be exponential in n (T(n)= a•2^n), that could cause a scalability problem; if n=10 that's 1024a, but what if n=100? 2¹⁰⁰ is an infinite time, we have to think of another way (algorithm) to solve the problem

That's the explaining, as for ur example

If T(n)=n², then

T(2n)=(2n)²=2²•n²=4•n²= 4•T(n)

If n=2, T(n)=4, T(2n)=4²=16
If n=8, T(n)=64, T(2n)=16²=256 =16•16=4•4•16=4•64